# How to split a string while conserving split elements as empty strings?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to split a string so that elements that have been "split" are conserved as empty strings, for example with a string of `"abaca"` I need the result to be `["", "b", "", "c", ""]` or a string of `"xzxzxz"` to result in `["x","","x","","x",""]` Simply adding empty elements does not work, as I do not know whether the element I split with may exist at the start or end of the string.

I've tried to use interspersing, however every method I've found for that has led to either an error or not what I wanted. Apart from that, I have not found anything else that could help.

Comment: Mind showing us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Is that just for characters, or are you also wanting to use words or longer strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this problem it's more convenient to match a regular expression than it is to split on one.

```
def doit(str, spl)
  sp = Regexp.escape(spl)
  str.gsub(/#{sp}|.+?(?=#{sp}|$)/).map { |s| s == spl ? " " : s }
end
```

---

```
doit('abaca', 'a')             #=> [" ", "b", " ", "c", " "]
doit('xzxzxz', 'z')            #=> ["x", " ", "x", " ", "x", " "]  
doit('nowiswasistoday', 'is')  #=> ["now", " ", "was", " ", "today"]
doit('iswasistoday', 'is')     #=> [" ", "was", " ", "today"] 
doit('i?si?s', '?')            #=> ["i", " ", "si", " ", "s"]
```

---

Here's an example of the steps.

```
str = 'iswasistoday'
spl = 'is'
```

```
sp = Regexp.escape(spl)
  #=> "is"
```

Here I am using [Regexp.escape](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.3/Regexp.html#method-c-escape) to escape characters of `spl` that have special meaning in regular expressions. We see that `sp` is the same as `spl` in this case, but in the last example above `?` has a special meaning in regular expressions (namely, to make matches optional or to match as few characters as possible). In that case `Regexp.escape('?') #=> "\\?"`. Continuing,

```
rgx = /#{sp}|.+?(?=#{sp}|$)/
  #=> /is|.+?(?=is|$)/
```

```
enum = str.gsub(rgx)
  #=> #<Enumerator: "iswasistoday":gsub(/is|.+?(?=is|$)/)>
```

Here I am using the form of [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) that takes a single argument and no block, returning an enumerator that generates matches of it's argument, here a regular expression. We can see the matches that will be generated by converting this enumerator to an array.

```
enum.to_a
  #=> ["is", "was", "is", "today"]
```

The last step follows.

```
enum.map { |s| s == spl ? " " : s }
  #=> [" ", "was", " ", "today"]
```

---

The regular expression has the following elements.

```
/
#{sp}     match the value of the variable sp
|         or
.+        match one or more characters other than line terminators
?         make previous match relunctant, matching as few characters as possible
(?=       begin a positive lookahead
  #{sp}   match the value of the variable sp
  |       or
  $       match the end of the string
)         end the positive lookahead
/
```

Comment: Nice.  Extra empty strings are inserted if there is more than one splitting pattern in a row though, so just removing all of them seems to work better than the shift.

Comment: @red, I will await word from the OP as to whether they want me to make the change you suggest.

Comment: `target of repeat operator is not specified: /?|.+?(?=?|$)/ (RegexpError)`
I don't use Regexp enough to really know what this means, but trying to use this spits this out

Comment: It appears that you got that error when `doit`'s second argument is `"?"`. If so, it needs to be escaped (`"\\?"` or `'\?'`) because a question mark is a reserved character in regular expressions. I've modified the method so that it now escapes characters as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [each_char](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/String.html#method-i-each_char) to iterate each character, then map them yourself.

```
'abaca'.each_char.map { |c| c.eql?('a') ? ' ' : c }
=> [" ", "b", " ", "c", " "]
```

```
'xzxzxz'.each_char.map { |c| c.eql?('z') ? ' ' : c }
=> ["x", " ", "x", " ", "x", " "]
```

Comment: Good idea! Updated.